# Multiline CATextLayer

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to recreate the multiline UILabel with a CATextlayer.

Is there a property for CATextLayer, or do I need to create it myself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but if you add a CATextLayer to a view, you can set it to have the same bounds as the view and if you enable the *wrapped* property on the CATextLayer, the text will word wrap. You can then also set the resizing mask on the layer so that changes to the view will be reflected in the layer.